# How to read Word, Excel Metadata by Vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office, metadata

i want to read the metadata (such as author, keywords, etc.) of the Word, Excel file by asp.net (vb). How can I do that ?

is there any sample, reference site ?

i found the following code online, but it return error for the 2nd statement (" Dim excelbook As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ")

```
Public Sub ReadExcel(ExcelFileName As String)

    Dim Wapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim excelbook As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    If Wapp Is Nothing Then
        Wapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    End If

    If excelbook Is Nothing Then
        excelbook = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Else
        excelbook.Close()
    End If

    excelbook = Wapp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)

    Dim _BuiltInProperties As Object = excelbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties

    If Not _BuiltInProperties Is Nothing Then
        excel_keyword = _BuiltInProperties("Keywords").Value
    End If

    If Not excelbook Is Nothing Then
        excelbook.Close()
    End If

    If Not Wapp Is Nothing Then
        Wapp.Quit()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [Social.MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/isvvba/thread/d1f072f1-0006-4e42-a2fe-f6b12d683636)

You can access the values using DSOFile (works for a whole bunch of different fileTypes), or more simply, you can access these properties like this in VBA

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    Dim mWorkbook As Workbook
    Set mWorkbook = Application.Workbooks(1)
    mWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author").Value = "the Author"
    mWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title").Value = "the Title"
    mWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Subject").Value = "the Subject"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the example for the [same](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=6514bc76687e775b&id=6514BC76687E775B!131). Or you can download from https://dl.dropbox.com/u/79986486/StackOverFlow9684368.zip {Temporary}

You can use openXML with C# or VB.Net to achive this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link doesn't work - you need a Microsoft account. The link redirects to https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1347262558&rver=6.2.6289.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Fskydrive.live.com%2F%3Fcid%3D6514bc76687e775b%26id%3D6514BC76687E775B%21131&lc=2057&id=250206&mkt=en-GB&cbcxt=sky